# Is there a way to "flatten" KQL results into summary columns?

Tags: kql

Given the following dataset, is there a simple/efficient way to produce a summary table in like the following using KQL, *ideally* without knowing the actual colours to be used in advance (i.e. column names are generated from the data values encountered)?

```
datatable ( name: string, colour: string )[
  "alice", "blue",
  "bob", "green",
  "bob", "blue",
  "alice", "red",
  "charlie", "red",
  "alice", "blue",
  "charlie", "red",
  "bob", "green"
]

+---------+------+-------+-----+
| name    | blue | green | red |
+---------+------+-------+-----+
| alice   |    2 |     0 |   1 |
| bob     |    1 |     2 |   0 |
| charlie |    0 |     0 |   2 |
+---------+------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
datatable ( name: string, colour: string )[
  "alice", "blue",
  "bob", "green",
  "bob", "blue",
  "alice", "red",
  "charlie", "red",
  "alice", "blue",
  "charlie", "red",
  "bob", "green"
]
| evaluate pivot(colour, count(), name)
```

| name | blue | green | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| bob | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| charlie | 0 | 0 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PTQoCMQxG94XeIXTVQk/gVcRF2gljIbYS01l5eOdHxZEhi5DHFz7egDpPYgIPFW90godKqWOE3Lh1%20dwQztYAOOSSyUVwifu8V5ZaWsgoRHWPfkLfR6HhjfIVhcsfPCo4DO5arblY8wSakDsqwb1MTf2msKj0qj7E1TC8AF8I60TzAAAA)